# How to filter multiline with awk, grep and/or powershell

Tags: awk, grep, xml, powershell

My scenario is I have a file that has the contents looking like this but longer. https://pastebin.com/q33wFdAX

I need to remove each occurrence of

```
        <category>Games</category>
</game>
```

If the category has data in there we don't want to remove it. So basically if I can just match this double line exact and invert like grep -v then I can output to a new file without those lines.

I will have more than just this category so I will need to be able to use several or statements. Example of the regex I'm using in notepad++ to accomplish this manually

`(^\s+<category>Games</category>\s+</game>$|^\s+<category>Applications</category>\s+</game>$)`

Bonus points if you can get me a simple way to do this in powershell too, I'd like to be able to do this on either OS. I'm not extremely good with advanced regex, awk etc.

Comment: It looks as if someone has botched an edit on the file. It would have been easy to work with the file using `xmlstarlet`, but since it's now a broken XML file, that won't work. Do you have the original file someplace (backup?) and what did you intend to do to _that_ file? It's probably easier to do that than to fix up a broken XML document.

Comment: Yes I have the orginal. They're straight from Redump website. What I'm doing is removing all the mentions of Roms that aren't USA. The way I've been doing this is by say removing all likes that contain (Europe) but then we're left with what's in the past bin. I've been doing all this manually with notepad++ which doesn't take too long, but I would like to automate it

Comment: Once it's in this position though in notepad++ it's real simple. Just bookmark all the lines matching `^\s+<category>Games</category>\s+</game>$` and then remove all bookmarked lines.

Comment: Where is the original file. The edits should be done using an XML parser, not by hand, not by `sed`, not by `awk`. It is _easy_ to do this with `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: http://redump.org/datfile/psx/
This is the original file. This is my regex string for the locals I wish to remove `(\(Europe\)|\(Europe, Australia\)|\(Japan\)|\(Germany\)|\(Sweden\)|\(Korea\)|\(UK\)|\(Asia\)|\(Italy\)|\(Israel\)|\(Scandinavia\)|\(Spain\)|\(Netherlands\)|\(Finland\)|\(Denmark\)|\(Greece\)|\(Russia\)|\(UK, Australia\)|\(Japan, Asia\)|\(France\)|\(Australia\)|\(Portugal\)|\(China\)|\(India\)|\(Spain, Portugal\)|\(Switzerland\)|\(Belgium, Netherlands\)|\(Poland\)|\(Brazil\)|\(Latin America\)|\(Croatia\)|\(Japan, Korea\)|\(Austria\)|\(Norway\)|\(Ireland\)|\(Belgium\))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given [the *original* file](http://redump.org/datfile/psx/), the following will delete all titles that does not mention `(USA)` in the title's `rom` node's `name` attribute:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -d '//game[not(contains(rom/@name, "(USA)"))]' file-orig.xml >file-new.xml
```

The XPath expression `//game[not(contains(rom/@name, "(USA)"))]` selects all `game` nodes that has at least one `rom` sub-node that has a `name` attribute that does *not* contain the string `(USA)`.  These are selected for deletion.

The output is written to a new file using a redirection on the command line.

After looking at the XML data for a short while, I noticed that instead of looking at tho `rom` nodes, it appears to be enough to look at the main `game` node's `name` attribute:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -d '//game[not(contains(@name, "(USA)"))]' file-orig.xml >file-new.xml
```

This deletes all games that does not contain `(USA)` in the `name` attribute of the `game` node.

The file that I downloaded will contain 1979 titles after deleting all non-`(USA)` titles.

To additionally filter out all non-`Games` categories:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed \
    -d '//game[not(contains(@name, "(USA)"))]' \
    -d '//game[category != "Games"]' file-orig.xml >file-new.xml
```

This leaves 1474 Games titles.

Just for fun, to sort the game titles by their total *size*:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed \
    -d '//game[not(contains(@name, "(USA)"))]' \
    -d '//game[category != "Games"]' file-orig.xml |
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//game' \
    -v 'sum(rom/@size)' -o ' ' -v '@name' -nl | sort -n
```

Comment: I like where this is going. It seems like this would delete Games that are denoted region less (World) or multi-region (USA, Canada). Sometimes I come across these. I would rather do it reverse and delete the ones named (Region) rather than delete not (USA) if that makes sense. I know it would be a longer script, but would protect me from over deleting and missing a game.

Comment: @volitank Just use `xmlstarlet ed` followed by a repeat of `-d '//game[contains(@name, "(someregion)")]' -d '//game[contains(@name, "(someotherregion)")]'` etc. for each region.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like this is the better way to work with it. Time to get some testing done. Thanks!

Comment: Well this is a bit unfortunate but it seems like the windows version of xmlstarlet is old or something. The commands don't work the same way.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the windows verson. Turns out is was a quotes issue. Changed it to `./xml.exe ed -d "//game[contains(@name, '(Japan)')]" test.dat` for windows